# how to make a function that makes functions?

Tags: javascript, function, console

ok so, it's 3am here and this stupid issue is keeping me up, bothering me all night long,
basically what i was trying to do is to make a function that takes an existing function as a parameter to return a constructor function, maybe this will be obvious reading my code

```js
var f = function() {
  return function(p) {
    return document.createElement(p)
  }
};
var x = f();
alert(x); //alerts function(p){ return document.createElement(p)}
var n = x("div"); //it creates div Element
alert(n); // alert [object HTMLDivElement]
```

the code above works just fine but i want to use variables instead of putting the createElement directly inside the constructor function, i want to pass it as a parameter to the function f like this

```js
var f = function(dd) {
  return function(p) {
    return dd(p)
  }
};
var x = f(document.createElement);
alert(x); //alerts function(p){ return dd(p)}
var n = x("div"); //doesn't createElement
alert(n); //doesn't alert
```

in addition to that , the last code outputs something weird in the console illegal invocation, I have no idea whats wrong wmy code, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the `createElement` method to the `document` object. Otherwise, you're calling a method, but it doesn't have the proper context.

```js
var f = function(dd) {
  return function(p) {
    return dd(p)
  }
};
var x = f(document.createElement.bind(document));
alert(x);
var n = x("div");
alert(n);
```

The arrow function version would be

```js
var f = dd => p => dd(p);
var x = f(document.createElement.bind(document));
alert(x);
var n = x("div");
alert(n);
```

Comment: thanks man, it works, if there are better ways to avoid typing the keyword function in my code, please let me know. im trying to make my code as short as possible

Comment: You can use arrow functions. But why are you trying to make it as short as possible? You should try to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: It's a coding challenge. To see who makes a game using the least number of coding characters

Comment: I've added the arrow function version, it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the createElement method to the document

`var x = f(document.createElement.bind(document));`